# how to manipulate controller's return data with pagination

Tags: php, laravel, api

In my Laravel application I'm using a controller to fetch database for a specific model that's called "Questions" which has a user_id foreign key indicating the creator user

my index() function looks like this:

```php
public function index()
    {
        return Question::orderBy('id', 'desc')->cursorPaginate(10);
    }
```

here I'm paginating results using cursor pagination-

at the current state this returns an object containing a `data` property in which questions are stored.

I need to add to those questions a property containing the creator user's profile picture link that is stored inside the User Model by the `profile_image_url` property.

in a few words what I'm trying to do is including some user data inside the questions themselves not to make any more requests to get creator user's data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join users table with questions table to fetch related user info.

Try this sql query:

```
public function index()
{
    return Question::query()
        ->select('questions.*' , 'users.profile_image_url')
        ->join('users' , 'users.id' , 'questions.user_id')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->cursorPaginate(10);
}
```